# Двойная агрегация в sql

Tags: sql, group-by

У меня есть БД со схемой

```
interface (string), timestamp(date), job_id (int), response_time (float)
```

Возможно ли создать ОДИН query который суммирует response_time по job_id и потом берет среднее  для всех job_id внутри interface?

Interface имеет много job_id, job_id всегда однозначно определен какому-то  интерфейсу.

Желаемая схема таблицы на выходе:

```
interface, average(job_ids)
```

Я создал query который делает это для одного interface, но мои попытки агрегировать по двум параметрам выливаются в ошибки.

Comment: Нужны примеры таблицы и запросов. Что вы пытались сделать? Что вы пытаетесь оптимизировать? Почему нужна эта оптимизация?

Comment: как то не понятно, что надо получить. приведите что ли пример входных данных и результат. И/или свой запрос, может из него будет понятнее. Например по тому что написано я вижу, что надо получить сначала сумму не в разрезе job_id, а в разрезе interface,job_id, иначе не ясно как сумма по job_id глобально, по всем interface должна влиять на каждый конкретный interface. А если сумма в пределах int-job получена, остается обернуть это в следующий уровень запроса и взять avg. И еще укажите какой SQL используется, вдруг у вас есть оконные функции и они будут полезны ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте подзапросы. Примерно так:

```
select Interface, avg(sum_response_time)
from ( select Interface, job_id, sum(response_time) as sum_response_time
       from [your-table]
       group by Interface, job_id) as tbl
group by Interface
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT interface, SUM(response_time) / COUNT(DISTINCT job_id) average
FROM [your-table]
GROUP BY interface;
```